# Zero out few columns of a numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

i have a numpy matrix 10x10 and want to zero values in some columns, accordingly to a vector [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0] - how to do it with best performance? using other python libraries is also acceptable, if work better

Comment: What do you mean by "according to a vector"? You mean you want to zero out the columns where the corresponding vector element is 0? Or the ones where it's 1? Or something different?

Comment: If it's one of those, notice that multiplying a value by 0 zeroes it out, and multiplying a value by 1 has no effect, so, what do you think happens if you multiply a 10x10 array with a 10-element vector of 0s and 1s? (If you don't know, try it out in your interactive interpreter.)

Comment: For anything more complicated, you can build a vector of bools out of the array in some way (e.g., `v>0`), use it to mask off part of the matrix (e.g., `m[v>0]`), then just assign `0` to the result (e.g., `m[v>0] = 0`). Try printing out all of those intermediate values to understand how that works.

Comment: i want to put zeros in columns, where vector has zero. yes, multiplying with this vector will work the same, but i guess that there is a faster solution.

Comment: there is a command m[:, [1,2,3,4,6,7,9]]=np.zeros(10) but this requires creating vector [1,2,3,4,6,7,9] based on [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0] (can this be done quickly?)

Comment: Why do you think multiplying isn't fast enough? It will probably be faster than masking with a bool array. And for a 10x10 array, both will be so fast that you'll barely be able to measure the difference, much less notice it. But if it really does matter, just try it both ways and test it, instead of guessing.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is multiplication. Multiplying a value by 0 zeroes it out, and multiplying a value by 1 has no effect, so multiplying your matrix with your vector will do exactly what you want:

```
m = np.random.randint(1, 10, (10,10))
v = np.array([1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0])
print(m * v)
```

Output:

```
[[7 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 5 0]
 [8 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 6 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 9 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 6 0 0 1 0]
 [5 0 0 0 0 8 0 0 5 0]
 [5 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 9 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 9 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 9 0 0 8 0]
 [6 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 6 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 6 0 0 1 0]]
```

You were concerned that multiplying might be too slow, and wanted to know how to do it by selecting. That's easy too:

```
bv = v.astype(np.bool)
m[:,bv] = 0
print(m)
```

Or, instead of `astype`, you could use `bv = v == 1`, but since you end up with the exact same bool array, and I can't imagine that would make a difference.

So, which is fastest?

```
In [123]: %timeit m*v
2.87 µs ± 53.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [124]: bv = v.astype(np.bool)
In [125]: %timeit m[:,v.astype(np.bool)]
5.02 µs ± 161 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [127]: bv = v==1
In [128]: %timeit m[:,v.astype(np.bool)]
5.03 µs ± 134 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

So, the "slow" way actually runs in less than two thirds the time.

Also, it takes only 5 microseconds no matter how you do it—which is what you should expect, given how small the array is.

Comment: thnx! obviously, i want to process larger matrices, like 10000x10000, but i will check your methods and compare times :)